# how to write a command line script to enable auto recovery in selected AWS instances?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, argparse, amazon-cloudwatch

i have to write a command line script that can activate auto-recovery of any selected instance. i know how to set cloudwatch alarm manually, this time i have to do it using API and using argparse python library, i have to enable the ec2 instance. can anyone guide me please?!

Comment: Same question a couple of days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889976/write-a-command-line-script-to-enable-auto-recovery-on-selected-aws-instances

Comment: @hpaulj now i got what you guyz wanted to state.. :) anyways thanks for the help :)